# Add Open Graph Meta Tags to My PHP code

Tags: php, drupal

Newbie coder looking for guidance. I want to add Open Graph tags to my website, as specified by Open Graph. I looked where meta tags are called in a .php file from my Drupal theme. How to I format the html code to work in the php file? Sorry, I realize it's a beginner question.

**HTML CODE PROVIDED BY OPEN GRAPH**

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<title>The Rock (1996)</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg"
```

**TO BE ADDED TO THE BELOW PHP CODE FROM DRUPAL THEME:**

```
/* Add various META tags to HTML head. */
    function montreal_preprocess_html(&$vars){
      global $root;
      $meta_title = array(
        '#type' => 'html_tag',
        '#tag' => 'meta',
        '#weight' => 1,
        '#attributes' => array(
          'name' => 'title',
          'content' => theme_get_setting('seo_title')
        )
      );

      $meta_description = array(
        '#type' => 'html_tag',
        '#tag' => 'meta',
        '#weight' => 2,
        '#attributes' => array(
          'name' => 'description',
          'content' => theme_get_setting('seo_description')
        )
      );

      $meta_keywords = array(
        '#type' => 'html_tag',
        '#tag' => 'meta',
        '#weight' => 3,
        '#attributes' => array(
          'name' => 'keywords',
          'content' => theme_get_setting('seo_keywords')
        )
      );
```

Comment: It seems that the `#attributes` arrays should have something like `'property' => 'og:title'`, etc. See [adding open graph metatags to head](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37715/adding-open-graph-metatags-to-head).